# Merge Replication: Updates to Schema

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

We have a main SQL Server which replicates to two backup servers via continuous merge replication.

There are regular updates to the schema. Regular changes include:

1. Adding new tables and relationships with existing tables
2. Changing the data type of columns on tables already replicated

**What is the easiest way to maintain replication in such an environment?**

If changes are made to the publisher, some changes cannot be synced to the subscriber and the whole replication has to be setup again (agent + subscriptions).

These databases are too big to replicate in its entirety every time there is an update.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of SQL server you are running you can [initialize via a backup](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152488(v=sql.105).aspx). However, Microsoft has recommendations as to when it's appropriate to use this processes. Also need to make sure your security is setup properly as well.